# Do not automatically restart on system failure

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-panic

I need to know: how do not automatically  restart GNU/Linux after a critical system failure
(kernel panic). For some reason the pc is rebooted, actually throws the error
screen Reboot just moments before, but I can't to read it before you reboot.
I tried using:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/panic

sysctl -p
```

and I find that the value is stored with

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/panic
```

but still does not work, does anyone know another way to indicate that no restart linux
after a failure?

Answer (score 2):

On NetBSD we add the following line to /etc/sysctl.conf to make it reboot automatically on kernel panic:

- ddb.onpanic=0

Perhaps that setting is what you need on Linux (but with a different value to make it not reboot)?  I don't know if it's the same though.